# String performacne: PHP vs MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Are there any performance concerns of note when using MySQL's `CONCAT()` function in a select query? Is it faster/slower/negligible to do a simple select, and format strings for a view using PHP after the result set from the database is returned? Or is a more complicated SQL query with multiple calls to `CONCAT()` that returns a string already formatted for the view a better approach?

ie is this:

```
select CONCAT(lastname, ', ', firstname) from people;
```

Faster/Slower/No difference from this:

```
<?php
    $query = 'Select lastname, firstname from people';
    ...

    $name = $data['lastname'] . ', ' . $data['firstname']; //OR
    $name = sprintf("%s, %s", $data['lastname'], $data['firstname']);
?>
```

Comment: before opening such question do your benchmark, it would be pretty easy

Comment: Why do you think it's even worth spending time to find that out?

Comment: No matter which is faster, consider you can very easily have more than one machine running PHP, but not without quite a lot more considerable effort have more than one MySQL box.

Comment: @zerkms adding it as a CW answer

Comment: what about design? What happens if later on you decide you need them separated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off in almost all cases by doing filtering and data massaging with the SQL engine versus on the web server.

Comment: I know this is old, but why? Can you provide some link?

Comment: Well, some searching will provide sources, but the main difference is that the SQL engine doesn't have to instantiate objects and already knows the schema of the data.  If you do this on the web-server (using PHP, C# or whatever), you will lose these benefits.  While realistically, this wouldn't even be noticeable unless you were doing lots of this, it is still best practice to do this kind of work in SQL

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are planning to do hundreds of thousands such operations at once, it will not matter where you do the string concatenation from a performance point of view. The possible time savings will be so minuscule, they will probably not even be measurable.